# navigation в React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

сделал навигацию в своем приложении, переходы выполняются по клику на кнопку, но мне необходимо вызывать функцию перехода с помощью другой функции расположенной за пределами default function Body(), вопрос как это сделать?

```
 const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Start' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name = "Start" component={Start}/>
        <Stack.Screen name = "Body" component={Body}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

```
export default function Body({navigation}) {
    GlobalEmail = email;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Text id='BodyText'></Text><Text id='EmailText'></Text>
          <Pressable id="ref" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Start')}><Text>нажми</Text></Pressable>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
```